# how to send back a post to a generated site

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to generate a page with the post connected to an id, I've got the id in to the node function witch I can see in the console but i don't know how i can render a new view with this posts content?

thankful for all ideas!

i think something is wrong with the search do to the fact that I don't get the item value in the console

in my node js file

```
router.param('id', function(req,res, next, id){
 console.log(req.params.id)
    db.collection('insights').find({_id:req.params.id}).toArray(function (err, items)       {
    res.json(items);
    console.log(items)
});
res.send(items);
});

router.get('/share/:id', function(req, res) {
  res.render('contact');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `param()` callback is generally not for directly responding to requests (although maybe in case of error). It's to be used for loading data from databases, etc.

Here's what you might do:

```
router.param('id', function(req, res, next, id) {
  db.collection('insights')
    .find({_id: id})
    .toArray(function(err, items) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return res.send(404);
    }
    req._items = items;
    next();
  });
});

router.get('/share/:id', function(req, res) {
  res.render('contact', { items: req._items });
});
```